# Hosted solution to extract data per namespace in Azure AKS

Tags: azure, kubernetes, monitoring, kubectl

We have couple of clusters running in Azure using AKS service. In clusters we are running multiple projects, each one of them has different namespace, naturally.

I would like to extract data about number of pods, their status and conditions etc. for specific namespace.
It is fairly easy to do locally using `AZ CLI` and installing `kubectl` (to get namespaces names) and then we can either stay in `kubectl` or use powershell `Az.Aks` [module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.aks/?view=azps-4.5.0) to extract these information.

I would like to have this process fully automated and scheduled. My first thought was Azure Runbook but it is not supporting AZ CLI.

What would be the best way to achieve what I have mentioned above? I believe the best way would be to use only `kubectl` commands, but how can we trigger them automatically? Is a pipeline in Azure Devops a solution?

Thanks,
Rafal

Comment: "Is a pipeline in Azure Devops a solution?". Sure is, sounds actually like a very valid solution for your case

Comment: Yea, it actually popped up while I was writing this post :) will try this way

Comment: Hm, I was trying to use Kubernetes@1 (kubectl) task. Get command returns only json output.

Comment: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/5032
I have found a proposed workaround here. Do you think it should be done in similar way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Azure Automation via RUnbooks, but just like Azure CLI you were trying you can do it through PowerShell. Runbooks can also be done using Python but for now only Python 2 is supported, and the same task can be done using Azure Functions but with so many different languages like C#, Java, Python and so many more.

Runbooks
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-runbook-types#:~:text=PowerShell%20Workflow%20runbooks%20are%20text,the%20runbook%20into%20Azure%20Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-runbook-types#:%7E:text=PowerShell%20Workflow%20runbooks%20are%20text,the%20runbook%20into%20Azure%20Automation).

Azure Functions
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-powershell

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. When it comes to Runbooks, I haven't found any documented working way of configuring it (using kubectl). Do you have any solution in mind?:)

Comment: honestly i have never tried it but I have forwarded the link to this post to a team mate of mine who is sort of k8s guru so he might have answer for you on this.

Comment: so after talking with my colleague i found out the easiest way would be to use Azure DevOps, In Azure DevOps you can use Pipeline and in one of the pipelines you can do this very easily, set up a schedule and emails the results after the job finishes.

Comment: Thanks @HassanRaza. I have issues with Kubernetes task though, look my first post. [github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/5032](github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/5032).